# Shuffling tables in an ordered way

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, character, tidyverse

I am really not sure if there is a technical term for what I am trying to do so I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I currently have 18 tables of 2x9 = 18 cells. These are token sets I am going to use in an experiment.

Each of these tables is characterized by a different linguistic context, especially a different main verb. For example here are my first two tables:

[image]

[image]

... and so on 18 times in total.

What I'd like to do is to "shuffle" these tables so that each table contains one of each condition in the 18 original conditions, and where no condition is repeated twice.

For instance, cell 1 would have "you'll can enjoy...", cell 2 will have "he'd could climb...", and so on in the first table, and the second table would move these contexts down one cell.

I'm not sure how to do this automatically (it is quite a pain to do by hand). Is there any way to do this in R?

Crucially I'm *not* trying to randomize. There is an ordered way in which the tables are shuffled.

All the best,

Cameron

Comment: Assuming you have the current indices of your cells as vector ```x``` and the desired indices of your cells as vector ```y```, you could do ```x[order(match(x,y))]```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I really understand what ```y``` would be though. Because I want that to be automatically defined. In the first resulting table, you would have cell 1 of original table 1, cell 2 of original table 2 (...) cell 18 of original table 18. In the second resulting table, you can't have any of the cells already used. So it goes cell 1 of original table 2 (...) cell 18 of original table 1. Until you have nothing left, and all 18 tables have been reordered with all unique cells.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're trying to do now. From each original table, you want a resulting table which first cell is the first cell of table *n*, where *n* is the number of the original table. For example, the first cell of the fifth resulting table will be taken from the first cell of the fifth original table. And then the second cell of the fifth resulting table will be cell 2 of the sixth resulting table, etc. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think that's about right, although we aren't obliged to choose the first cell of each table as the starting point. Not sure I'm clear.

Comment: Hm. If you aren't obliged to choose the first cell as the starting point, doesn't that introduce some randomness to it? How do you know which cell to start with? Does it not matter as long as it isn't repeated for the other tables?

Comment: Maybe I'm getting it wrong. But yes, it doesn't matter as long as at the end, no cell is repeated for the other tables. I put a comment on another answer which might be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first I recreated your tables, using base R's `sentences` object to simulate each cell:

```
start_index <- seq(1,18*18,18)
end_index <- seq(18,18*18,18)
for (i in 1:18){
  tables[[i]] <- sentences[start_index[i]:end_index[i]]
}
```

Then wrote a function to loop through them, using the table index as the argument:

```
tablemaker <- function(n){
  new_table <- list()
  for (i in 1:18){
      new_table[i] <- tables[[ifelse(n-1+i > 18,n-1+i-18 ,n-1+i)]][i] 
  }
  return(new_table)
}
```

After that, we can map them:

```
new_tables <- purrr::map(1:18, tablemaker)
```

And then check to make sure all the cells are still unique:

```
> 18*18
[1] 324
> length(unique(unlist(new_tables)))
[1] 324
> length(unique(unlist(tables)))
[1] 324
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course! Technically the function I wrote isn't best practice, as you're not really supposed to have loops within functions. But since you're only working with a small number of tables, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
tab1 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 1"), ncol=2)
tab2 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 2"), ncol=2)
tab3 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 3"), ncol=2)
tab4 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 4"), ncol=2)
tab5 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 5"), ncol=2)
tab6 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 6"), ncol=2)
tab7 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 7"), ncol=2)
tab8 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 8"), ncol=2)
tab9 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 9"), ncol=2)
tab10 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 10"), ncol=2)
tab11 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 11"), ncol=2)
tab12 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 12"), ncol=2)
tab13 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 13"), ncol=2)
tab14 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 14"), ncol=2)
tab15 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 15"), ncol=2)
tab16 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 16"), ncol=2)
tab17 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 17"), ncol=2)
tab18 <- matrix(paste("cell", 1:18, ", table 18"), ncol=2)

l <- list(
    tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5, tab6, tab7, tab8, tab9, 
    tab10, tab11, tab12, tab13, tab14, tab15, tab16, tab17, tab18)

newtabs <- lapply(1:9, function(i)t(sapply(l, function(x)x[i, ])))
```

The `newtabs` object will be a list, where each element will be one of the tables you want.  For example, in the above, the first table is:

```
> newtabs[[1]]
      [,1]                [,2]                
 [1,] "cell 1 , table 1"  "cell 10 , table 1" 
 [2,] "cell 1 , table 2"  "cell 10 , table 2" 
 [3,] "cell 1 , table 3"  "cell 10 , table 3" 
 [4,] "cell 1 , table 4"  "cell 10 , table 4" 
 [5,] "cell 1 , table 5"  "cell 10 , table 5" 
 [6,] "cell 1 , table 6"  "cell 10 , table 6" 
 [7,] "cell 1 , table 7"  "cell 10 , table 7" 
 [8,] "cell 1 , table 8"  "cell 10 , table 8" 
 [9,] "cell 1 , table 9"  "cell 10 , table 9" 
[10,] "cell 1 , table 10" "cell 10 , table 10"
[11,] "cell 1 , table 11" "cell 10 , table 11"
[12,] "cell 1 , table 12" "cell 10 , table 12"
[13,] "cell 1 , table 13" "cell 10 , table 13"
[14,] "cell 1 , table 14" "cell 10 , table 14"
[15,] "cell 1 , table 15" "cell 10 , table 15"
[16,] "cell 1 , table 16" "cell 10 , table 16"
[17,] "cell 1 , table 17" "cell 10 , table 17"
[18,] "cell 1 , table 18" "cell 10 , table 18"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure exactly this is what I need. I'd need cells 1 to 18 in each table, something like this for the first table:

cell 1, table 1,
cell2, table 2,
[...]
cell 18, table 18

then in the second table, we move down a cell, since we don't want cells already used:

cell 1, table 2, cell 2, table 3 [...] cell 18, table 1 

And so on until we have all reordered tables with all unique cells.